# Derivation of equation for difference in specific heats at vaporization

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition

Derive the equation.

[image]

Here L refers to latent heat, T for temperature, C_s for specific heat capacity of saturated vapour and C_l for specific heat capacity of liquid.

I tried using Clausius Clapeyron's equation but couldn't obtain the result.
Please help.

Comment: An important realization in [deriving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausius%E2%80%93Clapeyron_relation) the Clausius-Clapeyron equation is that $\Delta G=0$ during a phase change and that $G\equiv H-TS$ by definition; therefore, $L\equiv\Delta H = T\Delta S=T(S_s-S_l)$. Now (1) take the derivative with respect to temperature and (2) recall the definition of the heat capacity.

Comment: Got it, thanks @Chemomechanics

Comment: @Chemomechanics thanks for the answer. Are  L and H equal. They do not match dimensionally as L(latent heat) is energy per unit mass and H(enthalpy) is energy. Rectify me if I am getting the meanings or dimensions wrong.

Comment: Either everything should be normalized to unit mass or moles or it shouldn't. As you note, the units wouldn't match up correctly otherwise. (Normalized enthalpy and entropy are sometimes written as $h$ and $s$, respectively, for clarity, in which case we would write $L\equiv\Delta h=T\Delta s$.)

Comment: Thanks @Chemomechanics